# VB Calculator Displaying 0 at all times, and incorrect if/then/else results

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a full calculator using Visual Basic, and I've seem to run into the following error. When I hit any operation button I get the wrong result from the if/then/else statements. instead of assigning all of the booleans etc. it gives me the error message that was only supposed to appear with user error, ie hitting an operation twice etc. After commenting this portion out, I found another error, after hitting equals the answer was always zero, and I'm unsure of why. Thanks for the help.

```
Public Class frmCalc
    Dim num1 As Decimal = 0
    Dim num2 As Decimal = 0
    Dim answer As Decimal = 0
    Dim cnt As Integer = 10
    Dim add As Boolean = False
    Dim mult As Boolean = False
    Dim div As Boolean = False
    Dim subt As Boolean = False
    Dim second As Boolean = False
    Dim dec As Boolean = False
    Dim crash As String = "Error!"
    Dim uCrash As String = "User Error."
    Dim first As Boolean = True
    Public Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + 1
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + 1
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = num1 + (1 / cnt)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = num2 + (1 / cnt)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + 2
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + 2
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = num1 + (2 / cnt)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = num2 + (2 / cnt)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + 3
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + 3
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = num1 + (3 / cnt)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = num2 + (3 / cnt)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        If (add = True) Or (subt = True) Or (mult = True) Or (div = True) Then
            add = True
            subt = False
            mult = False
            div = False
            dec = False
            first = False
            second = True
            cnt = 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(uCrash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + 4
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + 4
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = num1 + (4 / cnt)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = num2 + (4 / cnt)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + 5
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + 5
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = num1 + (5 / cnt)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = num2 + (5 / cnt)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + 6
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + 6
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = num1 + (6 / cnt)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = num2 + (6 / cnt)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnMult_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMult.Click
        If (add = True) Or (subt = True) Or (mult = True) Or (div = True) Then
            add = False
            subt = False
            mult = True
            div = False
            dec = False
            second = True
            cnt = 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(uCrash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + 7
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + 7
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = num1 + (7 / cnt)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = num2 + (7 / cnt)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + 8
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + 8
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = num1 + (8 / cnt)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = num2 + (8 / cnt)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + 9
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + 9
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = num1 + (9 / cnt)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = num2 + (9 / cnt)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnDiv_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDiv.Click
        If (add = True) Or (subt = True) Or (mult = True) Or (div = True) Then
            add = False
            subt = False
            mult = False
            div = True
            dec = False
            second = True
            cnt = 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(uCrash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnDec_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDec.Click
        dec = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
        If dec = False Then
            If first = True Then
                num1 = (num1 * 10)
            ElseIf second = True Then
                num2 = (num2 * 10)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(crash)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        ElseIf dec = True Then
            cnt *= 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnEquals_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEquals.Click
        If add = True Then
            answer = num1 + num2
        ElseIf subt = True Then
            answer = num1 - num2
        ElseIf div = True Then
            answer = num1 / num2
        ElseIf mult = True Then
            answer = num1 * num2
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(uCrash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
        MessageBox.Show(answer)
        num1 = answer
        num2 = 0
        first = False
        second = False
        dec = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnSub_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSub.Click
        If (add = True) Or (subt = True) Or (mult = True) Or (div = True) Then
            add = False
            subt = True
            mult = False
            div = False
            dec = False
            second = True
            cnt = 10
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(uCrash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        num1 = 0
        num2 = 0
        answer = 0
        cnt = 10
        first = True
        second = False
        mult = False
        add = False
        subt = False
        div = False
        dec = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        If first = True Then
            num1 = num1 - (num1 Mod 10)
        ElseIf second = True Then
            num2 = num2 - (num2 Mod 10)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(crash)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to reduce the code a bit and keep for example only one number, one operator and the equal button. There are about 50 (guessed) `If`s in your code and you don't even highlight one that causes problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems reversed. If `add = True` when an operator is pressed, it should give an error because it means that you already pressed add, not the other way around:

```
If (add = True) Or (subt = True) Or (mult = True) Or (div = True) Then
        MessageBox.Show(uCrash)
        Application.Exit()
    Else
        add = False
        subt = False
        mult = False
        div = True
        dec = False
        second = True
        cnt = 10
    End If
```

edit: I think that check could be replaced by `(second=true)`, too.